Would the question, on movies.se, regarding the feeling one gets after watching a dramatic movie on-topic here?
Is the question
The feeling after you watch a dramatic movie or great movie that remains inside you
on-topic here?

It seems a bit vague/overly broad to me.

I agree with Steven. The broad topic of the effect of movies, books, etc. on our behaviour, affect and cognitions is on topic. However, the particular question seems quite vague regarding what particular post-movie experience you are talking about.

Yes, but it won't do well here either without clarification, or at least some elaboration. [This is just a simplified version of @JeromyAnglim's answer, which I upvoted.]
